# Exists $n$ where multisets of nonzero digits of $n$, $2n$, ..., $2000n$ are equal?

Tags: nt.number-theory

As the question title suggests, does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that the multisets of nonzero digits of each of the numbers $n$, $2n$, ..., $2000n$ are equal?

Comment: Note that $1/7=.142857$ repeating, and that $n=142857$ works for $n,2n,\dots,6n$. So find a prime $p>2000$ such that $1/p$ has a full period, and use that period.

Comment: First example seems to be $p=2017$.

Comment: Am I missing something? The multiset of nonzero digits of n=p is {2, 1, 7}, for 2n it's {4, 3, 4}... not equal...